# Railo + Tomcat + IIS7 - Default/Blank Host Header

Tags: tomcat, iis-7, coldfusion, railo

**Quick question:**

Is there a way to set up a blank or default virtual host within server.xml simlar to setting up a blank host header in IIS?

**Lengthy Explanation:**

I've set up a Railo server following the guidelines explained here: http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2009/09/Railo-31-on-Windows-Server-2008-and-IIS7--Part-3-of-3.cfm

I want to set up an open default host header to catch all incoming domains (so I don't have to create a site in iis and then have to create a virtual host in server.xml evertime I need to create a new site. I'll have a "valet" that will lookup the domain in the database when a request comes in, and then forward to the appropriate subdirectory.

Traditionally in the past, using IIS and the default website, I could just set up a blank host header for the ip and set the home directory to Z:\defaultWebDir which would contain my "valet" logic.

**Problem:**

With IIS + Tomcat serving up CFM pages, Tomcat has to mirror IIS. Is there a way to set up a blank or default virtual host within server.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to have a blank host header in IIS, and a default  entry in your server.xml that references the site you want to catch domains.